# Prove that $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)^p\left(\frac{b}{q}\right)^q\leq\left(\frac{a+b}{p+q}\right)^{p+q}$

Tags: inequality

Suppose $p,q> 0$ and $a,b\geq 0$, prove the following inequality

$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)^p\left(\frac{b}{q}\right)^q\leq\left(\frac{a+b}{p+q}\right)^{p+q}$

I tried taking log on both sides but this does not make things easier. Is there a more neat way to tackle this problem?

Comment: I'd say rewrite it $(p+q)^{p+q}a^pb^q\le (a+b)^{p+q}p^pq^q$, start with $a=b=p=q=1$ and take partial derivatives on each side (maybe a bit tedious, but tried and true.)

Comment: @TimRatigan So consider both sides as functions of four variables?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I'm sure there's an easier way, though.

Comment: @TimRatigan Well..I think this would be painful, but maybe doable

Comment: @DonAnselmo Are there counter examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking logs as you tried, we have to show
$$p \log \frac{a}p + q\log \frac{b}q \le (p+q) \log \frac{a+b}{p+q}$$

As $f(x) = \log x$ is concave, using Jensen's inequality we have
$$\frac{p}{p+q}f\left(\frac{a}p\right) + \frac{q}{p+q}f\left(\frac{b}q\right)\le \log \left(\frac{p}{p+q}\frac{a}{p}+\frac{q}{p+q}\frac{b}{q}\right) = \log\frac{a+b}{p+q}$$
which is the same as above.

Comment: It is exactly what we call [log sum inequality] (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_sum_inequality) @Katoyu